# Property is not being written to, only read from in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, properties, call

I have created my own component which has a TFont in it along with
appropriate properties.

The component has the following property in the Public declaration

```
property CaptionFont: TFont read fCaptionFont write SetCaptionFont;
```

The procedure SetCaptionFont looks like this

```
procedure TMyComponent.SetCaptionFont(value: TFont);
begin
  fCaptionFont := value;
end;
```

I am trying to assign the Font name and Font size to my component with the following code:

```
MyComponent.CaptionFont.Name := fGlobalStandardFontName;
MyComponent.CaptionFont.Size := fGlobalStandardFontSize;
```

However, when putting a breakpoint at the line

```
MyComponent.CaptionFont.Name := fGlobalStandardFontName;
```

and then clicking the "Trace Into (F7)" debug button, the code jumps to the TFont code and
completely ignores the SetCaptionFont procedure.

I am expecting the SetCaptionFont procedure to be called.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SetCaptionFont()` is not called when assigning values to sub-properties, because you are not assigning anything to the `CaptionFont` property itself.

Even if it were called, your `SetCaptionFont()` is not implemented correctly anyway.  You are taking ownership of the source `TFont` and leaking your original `TFont`.  You need to use `Assign()` instead to copy the source `TFont` values into your existing `TFont`.

To detect sub-property value changes (including from `Assign()`), you need to assign on `OnChange` event handler to your `fCaptionFont` object, eg:

```
constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  fCaptionFont := TFont.Create;
  fCaptionFont.OnChange := CaptionFontChanged;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetCaptionFont(value: TFont);
begin
  fCaptionFont.Assign(value);
end;

procedure TMyComponent.CaptionFontChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.Paint;
begin
  // use fCaptionFont as needed...
end;
```

Comment: I was expecting just hat. Thank you. Is it possible to make it behave in a way that SetCaptionFont is called even when sub-properties are written to?

Comment: No. `TFont` is its own independent object. You have to use its `OnChange` event to know when any of its values have been changed.

Comment: Why not just create two properties? One for each subproperty of font you are accessing.

Comment: That is overkill if you want full `TFont` functionality.  `TFont` has 9 properties, are you doing to duplicate those in `TMyComponent`?  To make that feasible, you would have to remove the `CaptionFont` property so the user cannot access the `TFont` directly, bypassing your duplicate properties.  And what if the component has multiple Font properties? Are you going to duplicate those 9x as well?

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding this is placement of the assignment operator.

Property setters are called when you use the assignment operator on the property. The only way to make the property setter execute for your property is to write code of this form:

```
CaptionFont := ...;
```

You do not do this. Instead you write:

```
CaptionFont.Name := ...;
```

Here the getter for `CaptionFont` is used, and then the setter for `Name`.

That explains why the setter is not called.

Beyond that you implement the setter incorrectly. Your implementation is liable to leak the object that you created in the constructor, whose reference you hold in `FCaptionFont`. When you assign to `FCaptionFont` you lose track of that object.

The convention for properties that are classes, is to convert the action of setting the property into a call to `Assign`. This makes the property have value semantics rather than reference. The properties value is copied. The setter therefore looks like this:

```
procedure TMyComponent.SetCaptionFont(Value: TFont);
begin
  FCaptionFont.Assign(Value);
end;
```

Comment: Alright, thanks David. So if I understand this correctly, all I need to do is to put FCaptionFont.Assign(Value); in to the SetCaptionFont  procedure, and that procedure will be called when changing values of sub-properties of the TFont? Or does Remy's answer still apply?

Comment: That part of my answer is identical to Remy's. I'm not disagreeing with him at all. The reason I added this answer is for the first part. I tried there to explain, perhaps more clearly than Remy managed, why the setter was not called. Remy did explain it but I wasn't sure that you'd necessarily understood it fully and I really wanted to drive home the point that you need the assignment operator applied to the property to get the setter to fire. That's all.

Comment: I see. So it's still true that I cant apply any sub-properties via the setter? gotcha

Comment: Well, the setting isn't executing is it? That's the fundamental point of the question.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Is it against StackOverflow rules to make a new question where I ask how to make the code work the way I expected it to do? This question is as youre saying fundemtally asked to answer WHY the code is behaving the way it is, rather than how to make it behave in some other way.

Comment: The reason I'm asking if its against the rules is so that I don't get any warnings about a duplicate question.

Comment: Well, you can't make it work the way you expected it to work for the reasons outlined in both answers. I'd guess that if you ask the question then it would be a dupe. Perhaps you should be asking all this of Remy, whose answer you accepted.